Dropzone not accepting propriety onDrop
I want to create a dropzone in my React project but for some reason, even the code from their site gives an error
'use client'



import { ImageType } from "@/app/admin/add-products/AddProductForm";
import { useCallback } from "react";

import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone'

interface SelectImageProps {
  item?: ImageType;
  handleFIleChange: (value: File) => void
}

const SelectImage: React.FC<SelectImageProps> = ({
  item,
  handleFIleChange,
}) => {
    const onDrop = useCallback((acceptedFiles:File[]) => {
        
      }, []);
      const {getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive} = useDropzone({onDrop})
  return <div></div>;
};

export default SelectImage;

I get this error Argument of type '{ onDrop: (acceptedFiles: File[]) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DropzoneOptions'.
Type '{ onDrop: (acceptedFiles: File[]) => void; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<React.HTMLProps, PropTypes>': multiple, onDragEnter, onDragOver, onDragLeave
I have copied the code from their website, still same error multiple times, and installed Dropzone just as much
I was trying to create a dropzone but I guess that's but it's not working
